# Truffle console showing irrelevant balance irrelevant BN{ negative: 0, words: [ 16777216, 62077800, 20718012, <1 empty item> ], length: 4, red: null }

Tags: solidity, web3js, truffle, ganache

I'm using ganache network, truffle network, web3, chai and mocha.

while using truffle console in terminal it shows:
truffle(develompment)> balance

```
BN {
negative: 0,

words: [ 16777216, 62077800, 20718012, <1 empty item> ],

length: 4,

red: null }
```

what i'm try to acheieve is <BN  56bc75e2d6300000>

can you please help me i'm new to this field feel free to ask anything which i'm missing

**Truffle-config-js :**

```
  require('babel-register'); 

  require('babel-polyfill');

  module.exports = {

   networks:{

     development: {

       host: '127.0.0.1',

       port: '7545',

       network_id: '*'

     },
  },

  contracts_directory: './src/centracts',

  contracts_build_directory: './src/truffle_abis',

  compilers: {

    solc: {

      version: '^0.5.0',

      optimizer: {

        enabled: true,

        runs: 200

    },
  }

}}
```

Tether.sol:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that javascript doesn't support large numbers required by solidity so web3 wraps them in an BN object. You can make the more legible with .toString().

For example:

```
truffle(develompment)> balance.toString()
```

Comment: Hey Thanks for your effort i use this and it shows 1 million tether but when I put truffle(development)> balance its shows BN { negative: 0, words: [ 16777216, 62077800, 20718012, <1 empty item> ], length: 4, red: null } instead of <BN 56bc75e2d6300000>

Comment: @AhmedYarKhan It is a javascript / BN thing. I don't think you can change it, perhaps it changes depending on the node version.

Comment: thanks brother can i share its code to you so can check it and help me and also Thanks a lot man

Comment: @AhmedYarKhan Sure you can add the code to the question. What's the value supposed to be? What does balance.toString() print?